# Can this code create multiple "special" vectors?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm just figuring out environments and how to play around with them. In the code below, I understand that we are creating this list of 4 functions. But in this environment of makeVector, there is an object created, m and is assigned to null intially. What I don't understand (coming from a C language coder) is, how does this m stored?

I understand that makeVector has its own environment and has 6 things under it - x, m, set, get, setmean, getmean.

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
        m <- NULL
        set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
        getmean <- function() m
        list(set = set, get = get,
             setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
}
```

For example,

```
x1 <- makeVector(as.numeric(1:4))
x2 <- makeVector(as.numeric(1:5))
```

Now, my question is, does x1 and x2 both have their own copies of m or do they share the same object m?

Again, if they do have different copies of m, isn't makeVector like a class in C, with its own objects and functions? Can someone clarify, because I'm having a very tough time figuring it out myself.

Comment: They each have their own `m`.  Yes, there are similarities to object oriented programming.  Try `demo("scoping")` for a similar example.